# multiprocessing from a callback tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing

the problem is when I want trigger a process "multiprocessing" from a callback tkinter, specifically  from a  function tkinter's bind. the error begin here:

`File "c:\Users\Usuario\Downloads\engine_controller_ls\extractText\funciones\reproductor.py", line 598, in __init__     p.start()   File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start     self._popen = self._Popen(self)                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen     return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 336, in _Popen     return Popen(process_obj)            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 95, in __init__     reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)   File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump     ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj) TypeError: cannot pickle '_tkinter.tkapp' object`

**main.py**

```
from reproductor import MediaPlayer

def item_selected(event):
    """
    Evento invocado cuando el contenido de una carpeta es abierto.
    """
    item_seleccionado = arbol.selection()
    item = arbol.item(item_seleccionado)
    print(item)
    
    #Extraer la ruta del archivo y si encuentra espacios unirlos
    ruta = ""
    for element in item["values"]:
        ruta += element + " "

    
    #Iniciacion del video
    global reproductor_video

    # Cerrar el video para que no se abra en multiples ventanas
    if reproductor_video is not None:
        reproductor_video.ClosePlayer()
    
    reproductor_video = MediaPlayer(ruta, frame_visualizer, frame_botones_procesar, spinInicio=inBox_inicio, spinFinal=inBox_fin, spinActual=inBox_Actual, mainVideo=True)
    reproductor_video.update_progres_video()

arbol = CheckboxTreeview(frame_Tree_in)
arbol.bind("<<TreeviewSelect>>", item_selected)
```

**reproductor.py**

```
class MediaPlayer:
    def __init__(ruta, frame_visualizer, frame_botones_procesar, spinInicio=inBox_inicio, spinFinal=inBox_fin, spinActual=inBox_Actual, mainVideo=True):
        p = Process(target=self.funcion1)
        p.start()
        #p.join

    def funcion1(self):
        cont = 0
        while cont < 100:
            cont += 1
            print("contador =", cont)
```

I tried the same code from a main function and it executed perfectly, however from a callback this does not execute.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### Original

la solución esta aquí para los que la necesiten, en efecto si se puede lanzar desde un evento en tkinter de la siguiente manera:

---

#### Translated (Google Translate):

The solution is here for those who need it, in fact it can be launched from an event in tkinter as follows:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, log_to_stderr, get_logger
import time
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import ttk
import logging
import sys


def item_selected(event):
    
    my_objeto = objeto()
    button_eraser.config(command=lambda:my_objeto.lanzador(2))
    button_marco.config(command=lambda:my_objeto.lanzador(1))
    my_objeto.start_player()

class objeto:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        #self.start_player()
        pass
    
    def start_player(self):
        pass
        

    def funcion1(self):
        contador = 0
        while 1:
            contador += 1
            print("Func1: ", contador, self.palabra)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            
            if contador > 80:
                break
        
        q = Process(target=self.funcion3)
        q.start()
        #q.join()
    
    def funcion2(self):
        contador = 0
        while 1:
            contador += 2
            print("Func2: ", contador)
            time.sleep(0.2)
            if contador > 120:
                break
    
    def funcion3(self):
        contador = 0
        while 1:
            contador += 2
            print("Func3: ", contador)
            time.sleep(0.02)
            if contador > 200:
                break
    
    def lanzador(self,mode):
        log_to_stderr(logging.DEBUG)
        logger = get_logger()
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

        if mode == 1:
            self.p = Process(target=self.funcion1)
            self.p.start()
        elif mode == 2:
            self.p = Process(target=self.funcion2)
            self.p.start()
        
    def unir(self):
        self.p.join()
        print("Salio")

    def iniciar_multis(self):
        self.lanzador(2)
        self.lanzador(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass tkinter objects to a separate process. Multiprocessing uses pickle to make objects transportable, and as the error states, you can't pickle tkinter objects.

This is because, at their core, tkinter objects exist as objects inside an embedded tcl interpreter. There's simply no way for these objects to be moved or copied or shared with another process.

You will need to find a way to pass data to your separate process rather than have the process try to access widgets directly.